# Can you convert an Array of bytes to a Tuple?

Tags: scala, dataframe, rdd

is this possible to convert the signature of the function anotherMethod passed in myMethod to a Tuple?:

```
def myMethod(df: DataFrame, str: String, type: String, anotherMethod:  DataFrame => RDD[Array[Byte]]): Unit = {}
```

I am rather new to scala and I am not sure how you can cast an array of bytes to a Tuple: `yetAnotherMethod : DataFrame => RDD[(String, Array[Byte])]`

Thank you

Comment: It is certainly possible to write a function of type `Dataframe => RDD[String, Array[Byte]]` however without knowing the schema of your Dataframe and exactly what you want to achieve it is hard to provide any advice.

Comment: @TerryDactyl thats why I didnt write a function that made this conversion. Instead focussed on getting the result from anotherMethod and then converting the result from Array[Byte] to the required Tuple2

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar - Fair enough - I just didn't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: what is the size of your array. Tuples have a limitation on the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a small utility function that will convert Array[Byte] to a tuple

```
def convert(bytes : Array[Byte]) : (String, Array[Byte]) =((bytes.map(_.toChar)).mkString,bytes)
```